# Split string by a space

Tags: string, vb6

I have one string that has two words in it:

> Cat Dog

How can I split these up so I get:

`Str1 = Cat` and `Str2 = Dog`

Please note this is for *VB6*.

Comment: I didn't say google it, I said you could have easily done so and provided a link where OP could read more about it. I don't see how providing information on how to achieve the result is not constructive.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the [Split function](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb-string-array-functions-split-join-filter).

```
Dim output() As String
output = Split("Cat Dog", " ")
```

Would produce

```
output(0) = Cat
output(1) = Dog
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be an array? getting a mismatch error

Comment: Oops, sorry yes it outputs an array.

Answer (score 0):

or like this:

```
For Each i In output
  .... a even here
next
```